# when add plugin file transfer, then phonegap 3.4 run android. So it has error message

Tags: cordova

I develop a phonegap application i want to add file transfer plugin. But when i add  file transfer plugin. after i run it with device (phonegap run android). So the alert message shows like

```
    BUILD FAILED
    F:\SoftPhonegap\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The
     following error occurred while executing this line:
    F:\SoftPhonegap\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Com
    pile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    Total time: 2 seconds
    Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,c:\project\resource_
    map_phonegap\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=
    ant-gen
       [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

please help
```

Comment: phonegap which version you are working now ?

Comment: i work with phonegap version 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. You have to update the tools and plataform-tools, then remove android platform and add it again. It worked for me.

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```